# How to position text vertically in the footer?

Tags: html, css

I have 4 icons under a  tag, followed by a

Made by [NAME] in 2022, GitHub

.

However, I'm unable to position the text to align with my icons, which I've centered in the far right, center of the footer.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div class='footer'>

 <div class='icons'>
     <a href='https://github.com/'><img src='images/github.png' style="width:30px; 
        height: 30px;" class='github'></a>
     <a href='https://www.linkedin.com/in//'><img src='images/linkedin.png' 
        style="width: 30px; height: 29px;" class='linkedin'></a>
     <a href='https://www.instagram.com/'><img src='images/instagram.jpeg' 
        style="width:30px; height: 30px;" class='instagram'></a>
     <a href='https://www.facebook.com/'><img src='images/facebook.png' 
        style="width:30px; height: 30px;" class='facebook'></a>
     <p><em>Made by NAME in 2022, GitHub</em></p>
   </div>
 </div>
```

I'm not sure how to position them underneath the 'icons' class, which is why I classed each icon individually.

CSS

```
.footer{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: white;
}

.icons:link {
  padding-top: 1.7rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;

}


.github {
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.linkedin {
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.instagram {
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.facebook {
  margin-top: 30px;
 }

p {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-align: end;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your footer selector.

```
footer{
      background: white;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
  }
```

Is this the behaviour you were looking for?